# How to setup IIS?

Tags: iis

i want to setup IIS(internet information service) on my laptop. what is the setup formality or setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Installing IIS](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/iiiisin2.mspx?mfr=true)

This question should be moved to Server Fault however.  Also, once posted there, you should provide a lot more information about what version of Windows, what version of IIS, and so forth.

Also, if you're just doing development, Visual Studio comes with a small development server, so IIS installations aren't usually needed for development.

Comment: Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error